# What is the difference between a electrum server type F and P

Tags: server, electrum

As I am trying my first steps with Bitcoin, I ask you to ignore my potential ignorance.

With Electrum I have to choose a server of which there seem to be `F` and `P` type servers. What is their difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F: Full servers

P: Pruned servers

This is an old question, Electrum server are not F or P anymore.